# Check proxies with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I recently figured out how to use proxies with selenium, but I have run into an issue where it takes a long time for it to check if the proxy works. It can sometimes take up to 2 minutes for selenium to say the proxy doesn't work. Is there a faster way to check if my proxies work?

Comment: Please share the related code block, so we can understand better what the issue is

Answer (score -1):

Selenium doesn't have method for checking the proxy but you can Set the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete

```
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30) # wait 30 second
    driver.get('http://...')
except TimeoutException as ex:
    print('Timeout Exception: ' + str(ex))
```